# Show all my Folders from a Folder in Flutter Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Hey I use Firebase Storage as Backup Opportunity for my App and have a users folder. Inside this folder there are a lot of folders which's name is the UID from a User.

Example:
users/bahjdbhjabdjabggjd/file.txt
users/bhsabhadadnhbann/file.txt
users/hbashdbadjadjajdgg/file.txt

I need a opportunity to list all foldernames in a array.

Goal:
[bahjdbhjabdjabggjd, bhsabhadadnhbann, hbashdbadjadjajdgg]

I didn't found a way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reviewing the [documentation for listing files and folders](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#listing-files--directories).  Just build a [Reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference-class.html) to the prefix you want to query, and call [listAll()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/listAll.html) on it.  For exmaple, copying from the documentation:

```
Future<void> listExample() async {
  firebase_storage.ListResult result =
      await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref("users").listAll();

  result.items.forEach((firebase_storage.Reference ref) {
    print('Found file: $ref');
  });

  result.prefixes.forEach((firebase_storage.Reference ref) {
    print('Found directory: $ref');
  });
}
```

It might also help to also record all your files in a database for easier querying, since the API of listing files is somewhat limited.